# Refresh page on multiple computers/browsers after query

Tags: php, javascript

I'm making a small php game for school. It has to be some kind of multiplayer game called four in a row/four in a line, whatever you want to name it.

Because its a multiplayer game and my playing field is saved in a database, I want to refresh the 'gamefield' if a user is making an action on the page. Like if he inserts a chip in the field, the other user must see it as well, and they have to switch turns. So how can I refresh the page on both computers/browsers when only 1 person is making an action on that page? So that both computers/browsers see the newly inserted chip in the field and the switching of a turn?

Comment: check the db for changes with ajax every X seconds, reload page if needed

Comment: Sounds like you need to start to investigate the wonderful world of AJAX.

Comment: you probably want to use AJAX for this. It's a much better user experience for the game field to silently refresh itself than for the browser to be forced to reload the whole page.

Comment: I suggest you to read about comet, websockets, long polling =)

Comment: Don't reload the page, update the needed elements based on the ajax results.  Also, you're not going to get a concise answer in this thread as it's a larger project you're tackling.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: Maybe you are right, but I tried only to suggest the right direction. The full answer will take several pages to explain.

Comment: i am right, suggestions are comments, and should not be posted as answers.

Comment: I suggest you examine [Meteor](http://meteor.com/), a javascript library that enables exactly this sort of live updating. It utilizes AJAX, but it will simplify the required coding.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Looks like I'll have to start learning AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

The web server usually do not initiate connexions to the browsers. You can check periodically from all computers/browsers if the state of the game changed. Ajax probably fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeOut()` or `setInterval()` to call a function, which makes a AJAX request for a field update. I would also advise to use jQuery to avoid writing everything from scratch.